# Understanding SOAP and Spock testing, No Such Property error

Tags: java, soap, spock

So I'm having troubles with the following code, and I can't see what the issue is. I've made multiple attempts, as shown in the commented out code, but it hasn't seemed to alleviate the issue.
Every time I attempt to run the test, I'm getting the error: "No such property: exp for class: SpockTestSOAP". Any help would be much appreciated.

```
@Test
@Unroll
public void 'Web service generateSolution correctly truncates integer division: (#exp) is #expectedResult'() {
    /*when: 'the an integer division expression is evaluated'
    String result = generateSolution(exp);
    then: 'the result correctly truncates the exact expression'
    result == expectedResult*/
    expect:
    generateSolution(exp) == expectedResult
    where:
    exp || expectedResult
    "1/3" || "0"
    "5/2" || "2"
    "13/8" || "1"
    "126/5" || "25"
}
```

Comment: There's no need to annotate it with `@Test`.

Comment: Please post the real test and the complete exception, as this example works without errors